# Proper way, in Spring Boot Camel XML/YAML route, to gather info for parameterized SQL call

Tags: apache-camel, camel-sql

I am using the following approach in designing an application, but I am not sure whether this is the appropriate way of handling things.  Any advice appreciated.

I have a String body with multiple lines, each line containing a field name and value.

To use parameters in the SQL, I want to set headers in Camel.  I use split and aggregate to send one line at a time to a route which sets a header, and in the aggregation, I merge the headers.  This allows me to then issue a SQL call in YAML using the :#${header.x} syntax for parameterized fields.

While this works, I am suspicious that I'm taking a long way around and there is a more straightforward approach.  I'm assuming that I need the values in headers in order to send them in as parameters to a prepared statement to bypass the possibility of SQL injection.

Am I missing a more straightforward approach, or is this how it's typically done?